# How to disable selected field in $('#bootstrap-table')

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-table

Expected Result: If row.updated_status equals to '1', will disable this two field 'UOM' & 'allocated_qty', else remaining.

Issues: Failed to disable the both fields.

```
"columns": [
{
    "field": "id",    "title": "Id",    "visible": false
},
{
    "field": "product__name",    "title": "Product"
},
{
    "field": "uom",    "title": "UOM",    "formatter": "uomFormatter"
},
{
    "field": "allocated_qty",    "title": "Alloc. Qty",
    "editable": {"mode": "inline"}
}],
"rowStyle": "rowStyle"
```

In javascript:
For field 'UOM':

```
function uomFormatter(value, row, index){
    var uom_list = row.uom_list;
    var product_id = row.product_id;

     if(product_id != null && product_id != ''){
         if(row.updated_status == 1){
             if(uom_list != null){
                  var html = '<select class="form-control defaultpicker uom_list" data-row-index="' + index + '" disabled>';
                  ...the following codes...
             }else{
                  ...the following codes...
             }
         }
         else{
             if(uom_list != null){
                  var html = '<select class="form-control defaultpicker uom_list" data-width="120px" data-row-index="' + index + '">';
             }
         }
```

For Field 'allocated_qty':

```
function rowStyle(row, index) {
    if(row.updated_status == 1){
           $('#bootstrap-table').bootstrapTable('disabledColumn', 'allocated_qty');
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be disabled, not disable:

```
var html = '<select class="form-control defaultpicker uom_list" data-row-index="' + index + '" disabled>';
```

Comment: Tq..and Do u have ideas for disable 'allocated_qty?'

Comment: they are totally different.. so cant do same thing.

Comment: Just write the same markup with `disabled` for `allocated_qty`.